# How can I find out the URL of EJBs on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: java, ibm, websphere

I've just deployed an Enterprise Application to WAS.  How can I find out which ports it is listening on?

Answer (score 1):

Use the admin console. Servers->Application Servers->{Servername}->Ports

There you will find all your ports that are available for your WAS instance.